# Why would dpkg not auto-rename .conf files on --unpack on an installed package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I was testing a few things and was wondering about the difference between `--auto-deconfigure` and `--unpack`.

```
dpkg --auto-deconfigure --install P.deb
```

If P has a Break field such as:

```
Break: B
```

and B is currently installed, then `dpkg deconfigures B` with a new status of *"half-configured."*

Similarly, you could *"unpack"* B first:

```
dpkg --install B.deb
...
dpkg --unpack B.deb
dpkg --install P.deb
```

In which case B new status is *"unpacked."*

However, in both cases the `/etc/B.conf` file stays right there. So it looks like the package is still fully installed.

My question is: Why wouldn't `dpkg` remove or rename `B.conf`? Because when I just do the `--unpack` the configuration file is named:

```
/etc/B.conf.dpkg-new
```

which makes sense. In that case B is really not configured!

It seems to be that the `--auto-deconfigure` or `--unpack` commands should also rename the `/etc/B.conf` as `/etc/B.conf.dpkg-new` then a `--configure` can restore the file as expected.

I guess that most software do not care whether a `.conf` exists and thus whether it is there or not doesn't make much difference in the end. Would that be the reason why they can as well leave it in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the package is purged, it's configuration files won't be deleted.

Configuration files can be modified by users, so we don't delete them unless requested.

Comment: Still, the status between dpkg --unpack and dpkg --install + dpkg --unpack is not the same. It seems to me that then the --configure would have to handle a quite special case...

Comment: What matters is that it isn't configured. Not precisely how much it is configured. It's perfectly acceptable for a sysadmin to provide a configuration file for a package before unpacking it, for example.